# No content shown in RecyclerView in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView in a NestedScrollView in a CoordinatorLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rclIngredients"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is how I initialize my RecyclerView

```
RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rclIngredients);
LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(data);
rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The scrolling layout works, but there is no content shown. Under my ImageView there is just blank space. My RecyclerView does not get populated. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting recyclerview inside nested scroll view.

Use it without the nested scroll view.

Do add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`
Attribute to your recyclerview.

Comment: Wow that fixed it, thanks @prashant-solanki ! it even fixed another bug where the ToolBar wouldn't collapse when I was scrolling down.

Comment: @NicolasZawada You're welcome! I've created a library for simplifying recyclerview usage. You won't need to make recyclerview adapters for every recyclerview. Just take a look at it. [ Snap-RecyclerView-Utils](https://github.com/prashantsolanki3/Snap-RecyclerView-Utils).

Comment: Looks very useful. I bookmarked it, might use it in a later project, thanks again. @prashant-solanki